# IE - position fixed z-index draw issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I don't even know how to ask this question.  This issue is only in IE.

The page has a fixed position header and a slide panel that is also fixed positioned.

When the slide panel is scrolled down, and then back up, it creates these horizontal lines, almost like a vertical sync issue.  When any other elements within the slide panel are hovered, the lines disappear over that element.  Best I can do to explain this is a screen shot.

[image]

Best I can figure it's something with how IE is rendering the page and it's a graphics driver bug?  I have no clue.  This is outside my realm of knowledge.

**EDIT** I didn't post any code because it would be A LOT of code.  I'm looking for direction on why IE would do this.  It seems more like a bug with the rendering engine than CSS or HTML.

Comment: Either way it seems like this is not something web developers will fix :) Anyhow, does this happen on other computers or just yours? Because if its just yours its more likely to be a graphics driver than a renderer.

Comment: @somethinghere: IE11 for sure.  Haven't tested other IE versions yet.

Comment: I can't the pictures but possibly IE related software rendering settings and or an IE reset ??http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/horizontal-lines-appear-when-viewing-site-with-internet-explorer-11

Comment: @Plummer I kind of meant testing IE11 on another computer to see if the issue is related to your hardware or is general for the software :)

Comment: What about all the janky text we're seeing here -- is that normal?  it looks like something I've sometimes seen when I save a text/html file with the wrong encoding....

Comment: @wwwmarty: that would be my lovely QA testers mashing their faces into the keyboard instead of writing out proper test cases based on the acceptance criteria.

Comment: @somethinghere: sorry, I didn't specify.  Yes, it's happened on all isntances of IE11 that have tested it.  I noticed the slidePanel was "under" the header by 2px.

Comment: @AlanStephens: App uses Bootstrap, which has it's one resets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the root cause of the rendering bug was never resolved, there was a workaround.

The slidepanel was positioned 2px "underneath" the nav-bar on the Y-axis.  After some fiddling, I position the slidepanel so that it would no longer be "underneath" the nav-bar, and viola.  No more weird lines.

Comment: Two years on this just saved me a lot of pain.  +1px to the margin-top of an element and the stupid line artifacts stop. Thanks!